# Matrix representation of idempotent operator

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$, and $:  → $ be an idempotent operator, i.e. $P^2=P$. It can be proved that $( − )$ is also an idempotent operator and $ker(P^m) = im((I - P)^n)$ for all $,  ≥ 1$. 
The question is to show that under some choice of basis $B$ of $V$, there exists $0 ≤  ≤ dim()$ such that the matrix representation of $P$ with basis $B$ is 
 $$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0& ... & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & ... & 0 & 0& ... & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & ... & 1 & 0& ... & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0& ... & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0& ... & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
where there are k ones in total.

I think it can be solved by proving $(b_i)=b_i$ for $I=1,...,k$. But what is the next and how can prove this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem statement and is not showing any effort of you approaching the problem. Please edit the question to include what you have tried and where you're struggling. As of now the question is likely to attract down votes, close votes and not getting any answers.

Comment: Thanks. Some thoughts added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hints:* Proceed as follows:

- Show that for all $v \in im(P)$, we have $P(v) = v$.
- Prove that $ker(P) \cap im(P) = \{0\}$ and conclude that $V = im(P) \oplus ker(P)$.
- Take bases of $ker(P)$ and $im(P)$ö. This gives you a basis of $V$ (why?). Then calculate the matrix of $P$ with respect to this basis.

Comment: Helps a lot, thanks!